# I have no idea why i'm keep getting NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript. I did some code with no problems but when I want to make new code that will allow me to calculate call of my table I keep getting NaN and I don't know why.

This is my JS code

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
            }
            console.log(sumVal);
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML =  sumVal;
```

This is my table

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Code</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prenome</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                    <th scope="col">Frais de inscription</th>
                    <th scope="col">Le rest</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date de paiment</th>
                    <th scope="col">dure de paiment</th>

                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                   <tr>
                   <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                   <th></th>
                   <th id="val"></th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                 </tr>
               </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                   <tr> 
                    @foreach($students as $student)

                    <th  scope="row">{{$student->id}}</th>
                    <td>{{$student->student->student_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->student->student_last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->frais_inscription}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->Rfrais_inscription}}</td>
                    <td width="140" id="xd">{{$student->payment_date->Dfrais_inscription}}</td>
                    <td >{{$student->Afrais_inscription}} Mois</td>
                    <td ></td>

                   </tr>

                   @endforeach
              </tbody>
             </table>
```

I have tried another way just to know what I'm missing, and it did work fine; I got the results.

Here is the code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

console.log(parseInt(table.rows[1].cells[4].innerHTML) + parseInt(table.rows[2].cells[4].innerHTML));
```

Comment: Your `<tr>` is outside the `@foreach` loop.

Comment: debug: `console.log(i, table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML, parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML))` I am betting that will clear it up for you.

Comment: document.getElementById("val").textcontent =  sumVal like this ?

Comment: console.log(parseInt(table.rows[1].cells[4].innerHTML) + parseInt(table.rows[2].cells[4].innerHTML)); here you choose cell number 4 i am guessing that cell[0] not always have an integer value that is why you get to see NaN

Comment: but "i" need a value?

Comment: it's working fine i have only numbers on those cells. itried 0 and it did work fine

Comment: show me the student json data if you can please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for when `<tr>`'s innerHTML is empty. `parseInt("")` will return `NaN` and you can't increment `NaN` so the result will just be `NaN`.

See below.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
             if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML !== ""){
                sumVal +=parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);   
            }
console.log(sumVal);
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML =  sumVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill out some number and simply change your `innerText` to `textContent`.
I suggest you use `textContent` for security concern.

Console.log() for general debug purpose.

Plain html works fine.
I am not exactly sure how you fill out the number and the calculation part is executed individually before and after the filling.
If it always executes after the table filling. You want to make sure you input 0 if `$student->frais_inscription` is `empty`

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

console.log(parseInt(table.rows[1].cells[4].textContent));
console.log(parseInt(table.rows[2].cells[4].textContent));
console.log(table.rows[1].cells[4]);
console.log(table.rows[2].cells[4]);



console.log(parseInt(table.rows[1].cells[4].textContent) + parseInt(table.rows[2].cells[4].textContent));
```

```html
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Code</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prenome</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                    <th scope="col">Frais de inscription</th>
                    <th scope="col">Le rest</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date de paiment</th>
                    <th scope="col">dure de paiment</th>

                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                   <tr>
                   <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                   <th></th>
                   <th id="val">12334</th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                 </tr>
               </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                   <tr> 
                    @foreach($students as $student)

                    <th  scope="row">{{$student->id}}</th>
                    <td>{{$student->student->student_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->student->student_last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->frais_inscription}}</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td width="140" id="xd">{{$student->payment_date->Dfrais_inscription}}</td>
                    <td >{{$student->Afrais_inscription}} Mois</td>
                    <td ></td>

                   </tr>

                   @endforeach
              </tbody>
             </table>
```

Comment: when i do like it works fine. but as Matt said above it's because i did not account for <tr> been empty that' why i got NaN when i tried loop

Comment: @justalittlecloser  Depends on how you handle your logic,  just make sure input 0 if their is empty `val` from `for loop`.